# retrieve data from two tables in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

i have two tables in my database .
1 = properties (contain an image of property)    2 = builders (contain a logo of the builder)

i have retrieved the data from properties table and displayed in the table like this ..

```
  <?php



        while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){



            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td>".$list['id']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['owner']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['purpose']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['property_type']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['city']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['location']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['description']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['price']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['land_area']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['bedrooms']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['bathrooms']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['property_expire']."</td>";
            echo"<td>"."<img height='50' width='50' src='".$list['image_url']."'/>"."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"edit_property.php?id=$list[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete_property.php?id=$list[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";

            echo"</tr>";


            }


         ?>
```

**what i want :**
show all content of properties table which i have already done but i want to get the builder logo from the builder table as well...how can i ??

Comment: You can use join in query to retrieve data from 2 tables.

Comment: i am new to php and mysql ....will you please explain how to do???

Comment: I have added answer you can use same query.

Comment: simply maka a join query

Comment: thanks to all ....problem solved !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in your query.

```
Select P.propertyId, L.logoName from properties as P
Left Join logos as L ON P.logo_id = L.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple make a join query with both table `properties` and `builders`:

```
SELECT pr.propertyId, bu.logoName 
FROM properties as pr
LEFT JOIN builders as bu ON pr.logo_id = bu.id
```